# I want to change the document class paper format in latex

Tags: templates, cv, awesome-cv

i'm using awesome-cv template in latex. After opening it in pdf, it has a4 format. I've changed it to a5, letterpaper but in vain. I always have to zoom use button to see the full resume. But I want my resume to be shown in full page not by zooming all the time.

Comment: You can set your viewer to do that. If the option is fitwidth, is won't work even if the paper size changes.

Comment: IIRC,`hyperref` has an option to select the PDF view mode, however, this might only work with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

Comment: afaik, foxit reads that info, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this with `hypersetup` in your preamble. I don't understand *exactly* what you want to do, but take the following snippet and adapt at will:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  % PDF meta information
    pdftitle={My Duckument Title},
    pdfauthor={My Name},
    pdfsubject={A duckingly Interesting Subject},
  % Viewport settings
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    pdfcenterwindow=true,
    pdfstartview=FitH,
  % Further bells and whistles (settings pertaining to the looks and workings of the displayed PDF)
    linktocpage=true, % make page number, not text, be link on TOC, LOF and LOT
    pdffitwindow, % resize document window to fit document size
    colorlinks, % Link colors in the document
    linkcolor=#ff0000,
    citecolor=#0ff000,
    filecolor=#00ff00,
    menucolor=#000ff0,
    urlcolor =#0000ff,
    breaklinks=true, % lets links in the document break across lines
    pagebackref=true, % backreference by page number
}
```

The keys are for the most part self-explanatory imho. The rest are in the hyperref manual. Best is to just search for them there and read up on what they stand for, then use the ones that fit your bit. They are in section 3.3 onwards. For instance, `pdfstartview=FitH` will open the PDF and set the zoom level of the viewport (your PDF viewer of choice) to the page width of the PDF displayed.